# Why isn't my python flask website working on heroku?

Tags: python, flask, heroku, web-deployment

So I've uploaded my website which I made using html,css,flask,python and javascript onto heroku. But it is giving me this error message :

```
06-30T14:23:51.105143+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H14 desc="No web processes running" method=GET path="/" host=iptutorial-api-heroku.herokuapp.com request_id=fbf325a2-66d3-4a54-8a8a-b6c32769d19a fwd="86.190.136.60" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

So what does this mean?? and how can I fix it?? I've made the procfile and put this in it :

web: gunicorn iptutorial:app
release: python manage.py db upgrade

I've also installed gunicorn and the buildpacks for python. So why isn't it working??

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you have a procfile that declares that your application is a web application.

For example your Procfile should look something like this:

```
web: gunicorn run:app
```

where run is the name of your module that runs your app.

Comment: In that case share the module that runs your app. Lets look at it.